# How to write multiple images (subplots) into one image

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, matplotlib

I have two images that I would like to save as subplots in one image.

My current code works fine to display them as subplots.

```
import cv2 as cv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
image1 = cv.imread('someimage')
image2 = cv.imread('anotherimage')
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1), plt.imshow(image1, 'gray')
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1), plt.imshow(image2, 'gray')
plt.show()
```

OpenCV `imwrite` can't work in its simple form as it expects one image as input. I would like to save these subplots in one image for later visual analysis. How can I achieve this?

It can be side by side or on top of each other. Just an example :)

[image: Two images in one]

The example is just for demonstration purposes. I should be able to save multiple images into one the way like creating a subplot(x,y). For example,

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just for other readers:
One can simply use matplotlib.pyplot.savefig. It saves the subplots exactly the way its displayed with plt.show().

https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.savefig

For two images, the other two answers can be used too, I guess.

Resultant code should look this:

```
import cv2 as cv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
image1 = cv.imread('someimage')
image2 = cv.imread('anotherimage')
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1), plt.imshow(image1, 'gray')
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2), plt.imshow(image2, 'gray')
plt.savefig('final_image_name.extension') # To save figure
plt.show() # To show figure
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import cv2 as cv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
image1 = cv.imread('someimage')
image2 = cv.imread('anotherimage') 
final_frame = cv.hconcat((image1, image2)) # or vconcat for vertical concatenation
cv.imwrite("image.png", final_frame)
```

Comment: is it possible to adapt this to multiple images? I have at times more than two images which I would like to save to one image. So kind of need a bit generic solution.

Comment: I guess you can put the concatenation into an iteration loop as long as they are the same dimensions

Comment: found the solution, I can use savefig.

Comment: @utengr    Would you be able to expand on this? I am also looking for any easy solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `numpy.concatenate` for this purpose:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
image1 = cv.imread('someimage')
image2 = cv.imread('anotherimage')
final = np.concatenate((image1, image2), axis = 0)
cv2.imwrite('final.png', final)
```

`axis = 0` concatenates images vertically

`axis = 1` concatenates images horizontally

Comment: is it possible to adapt this to multiple images? I have at times more than two images which I would like to save to one image. So kind of need a bit generic solution.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution based on `add_subplot`.

I prefer to use `add_subplot` due to its ability to [create complex plot](https://towardsdatascience.com/customizing-multiple-subplots-in-matplotlib-a3e1c2e099bc)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

ls_image_pt=['path1.jpg','path2.jpg']
for idx, dpath in enumerate(ls_image_pt):
    sub1 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, idx + 1)
    image2 = cv.imread('dframe_0.png')
    sub1.imshow(image2, 'gray')


plt.setp(plt.gcf().get_axes(), xticks=[], yticks=[])
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```